# Making one slate in XCode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I am beginning developing with XCode, and I am starting doing some exercises and practises. I am trying to do an easy one, one drawing example in iPhone, an slate with one touch event, but I am doing something wrong; I am a little bit lost.

I create my HDPizarra class and I am triying to keep the moves. I have got one Erase button, with one IBAction that must clean the slate and restart the view; I put the lines in red colour and of 2 of width and I put the touch LocationInView of star and end. But it doesn’t go; it starts the view but when I touch the sreen nothing happens. This is the code:

```
-(IBAction)borrar: (id)sender
{

[lineas removeAllObjects];

}

- (id)initWithFrame: (CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
}
return self;
}

-(NSMutableArray *)lineas{
if (_lineas == nil) {
_lineas = [NSMutableArray new];
}
return _lineas;
}

- (void)drawRect: (CGRect)rect
{

if (!lineas) {
lineas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
}

CGContextRef contexto = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIColor * rojo = [UIColor redColor];

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(contexto, rojo.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(contexto, 2);

CGContextMoveToPoint(contexto, inicio.x, inicio.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(contexto, fin.x, fin.y);

CGContextStrokePath(contexto);

}


-(void)touchesBegan: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event{
UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
inicio = [touch locationInView:self];
fin = [touch locationInView:self];

[self setNeedsDisplay];


}

-(void)touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event{
UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
fin = [touch locationInView:self];
HDLinea * linea = [[HDLinea alloc] initWithRect:CGRectMake(inicio.x, inicio.y, fin.x,           fin.y)];
[self.lineas addObject: linea];
inicio.x = fin.x;
inicio.y = fin.y;
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The moves are from an HDLinea object, in one NSMutableArray; the code of .h is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HDLinea : NSObject

@property (readwrite) CGRect puntos;

-(id) initWithRect: (CGRect) puntos;

@end
```

And the one of the implementation is:

```
#import "HDLinea.h"

@implementation HDLinea
@synthesize puntos = _puntos;

- (id)initWithRect: (CGRect)puntos
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
self.puntos = puntos;
}
return self;
}

@end
```

Any idea? Thanks a lot!!